# Sorting a 2 dimensional array after a part of an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I'm trying to sort a 2 dimensional Numpy array by the last entries, especially the last 2 characters of the integer. What I can already do is sort the array by the last number accordingly.

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([[2,2,2,10006], [2,2,2,18015], [2,2,2,12002], [2,2,2,14005]])
print( a[a[:, 3].argsort()] )
```

The problem, however, is that the following comes out:

```
[[    2     2     2 10006]
 [    2     2     2 12002]
 [    2     2     2 14005]
 [    2     2     2 18015]]
```

But what I would like to have is (02, 05, 06, 15 -> last 2 charakters of the integer):

```
 [[    2     2     2 12002]
  [    2     2     2 14005]
  [    2     2     2 10006]
  [    2     2     2 18015]]
```

And now comes the exciting part, the whole thing is done for a lot of entries and of course I want it to be super mega fast, so I think I should do it without the conversion to a string, the slicing and the sorting with an own algorithm. Somehow I have absolutely no idea about this very special question. Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[7,8,9,10006],
              [10,11,12,18015],
              [1,2,3,12002],
              [4,5,6,14005]])

# extract the absolute value of the number modulus 100
# to get the two trailing digits
print(np.mod(a[:, 3], 100))

# you could directly replace them in the array
a[:, 3] = np.mod(a[:, 3], 100)


print(a[a[:, 3].argsort()])
```

Comment: Hello Joe, thank you so mutch! That was exactly what I was looking for!